# Can we construct a successor function from successive applications of those two functions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Let $f(x) = 5 \cdot x + 3$ and $g(x) = \frac{x}{8}$,

Is it possible to construct a function $s$ such that $s(x) = x + 1$ via successive applications of any of f and g?

Comment: Please provide more context to this. Is this a homework problem? Why do you want to find the answer to this specific problem (an application, for instance)?

Comment: It's not a homework problem, I have been wondering if that was possible on my own but could not find a proof myself and there is no informal/concise resources elsewhere on the Internet. I hope to get some ideas/hints.

Comment: How did this problem come up?

Comment: @mixedmath I was reading about the definition of the successor function in untyped lambda calculus. I understand that you need more context to get some sense of what a proof of this would look like and I wish I could help but really the context is not relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, a big composition of $f$ and $g$ involving applying $f$ a total of $k$ times and $g$ a total of $\ell$ times (in any order) will yield a function of the form
$$\frac{5^k}{8^\ell}x + A,$$
where $A$ is a constant that depends on the order of applications. Since $5^k/8^\ell$ can never be equal to $1$, the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you Pedro! If it is not possible to obtain a general successor function, can we define a "dynamic" function $s_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_n(n) = n + 1$ where $s_n$ is composed exclusively of f and g?

Comment: @ErwanAaron: This is a much harder problem. I suspect you may be able to do this for some specific values of $n$, but probably not for all of them. Now, even if this "magically" turns out to be true, finding an explicit formula or even a recursive formulation seems very hard.